# How do I associate an image file to Magic Disc

Tags: windows-vista, iso-image, file-association, virtual-drive

I am using Windows Vista and Magic Disc. Everytime I double click an ISO I want it to be mounted via Magic Disc. Is this possible? Defining a file association via the CP just spawns a new instance of Magic Disc.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use that program myself, but according to [this page](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-mount-iso-image.htm) indicates that `miso.exe -mnt <drive letter> "path\to\iso"` command line option will mount the specified.

You can specify the selected file when setting up a command line with `%1`, so the full command for the file association would be `"c:\path\to\miso.exe" F: "%1"`.

You can set a custom command line for a file association with [**Default Programs Editor**](http://defaultprogramseditor.com).

Go to File Type Settings -> Context Menu -> (.iso files). Then select the bolded default command and hit 'Edit'. Browse to the MagicDisc program, then append the `F: "%1"` part to the command.

If that command line parameter for Magic Disc is correct, that should set it as the default action when you double click .iso files.